# REST vs RPC for a C++ API

Tags: c++, api, rest, rpc

I am writing a C++ API which is to be used as a web service. The functions in the API take in images/path_to_images as input parameters, process them, and give a different set of images/paths_to_images as outputs. I was thinking of implementing a REST interface to enable developers to use this API for their projects (independent of whatever language they'd like to work in). But, I understand REST is good only when you have a collection of data that you want to query or manipulate, which is not exactly the case here. 
[The collection I have is of different functions that manipulate the supplied data.]

So, is it better for me to implement an RPC interface for this, or can this be done using REST itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like lcfseth, I would also go for REST. REST is indeed resource-based and, in your case, you might consider that there's no resource to deal with. However, that's not exactly true, the image converter in your system is the resource. You POST images to it and it returns new images. So I'd simply create a URL such as:

```
POST http://example.com/image-converter
```

You POST images to it and it returns some array with the path to the new images.

Potentially, you could also have:

```
GET http://example.com/image-converter
```

which could tell you about the status of the image conversion (assuming it is a time consuming process).

The advantage of doing it like that is that you are re-using HTTP verbs that developers are familiar with, the interface is almost self-documenting (though of course you still need to document the format accepted and returned by the POST call). With RPC, you would have to define new verbs and document them.

Comment: Any suggestions on what I will have to do to the C++ code for it to start processing as soon as I perform a POST operation? How do I link the `http://example.com/image-converter` from your example to the C++ code I've got?

Answer (score 1):

REST use common operation GET,POST,DELETE,HEAD,PUT. As you can imagine, this is very data oriented. However there is no restriction on the data type and no restriction on the size of the data (none I'm aware of anyway). 
So it's possible to use it in almost every context (including sending binary data). One of the advantages of REST is that web browser understand REST and your user won't need to have a dedicated application to send requests.

RPC presents more possibilities and can also be used. You can define custom operations for example.
Not sure you need that much power given what you intend to do.

Personally I would go with REST.

Here's a link you might wanna read:
http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/03/25/rest-and-rpc-relationship/

Answer (score -1):

Compared to RPC, REST's(json style interface) is lightweight, it's easy for API user to use.  RPC(soap/xml) seems complex and heavy.

I guess that what you want is HTTP+JSON based API,  not the REST API that claimed by the REST author
http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

Comment: His question is: should I use REST or RPC?